# .NET RegEx - Nesting and Recursion

Tags: .net, regex

I have the following html string:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Demo Website</title>
    </head>
    <body class="home">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 class="subtitle">Subtitle</h1>
        <h1 class="title">title</h1>
        <p>paragraph...</p>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need all possible `<tag>...</tag>` irrespective of their nesting level.
So the output should be like:

```
<html> ... </html>
<head> ... </head>
<title> ... </title>
<body class="home"> ... </body>
<div class="container-fluid"> ... </div>
<h1 class="subtitle"> ... </h1>
<h1 class="title"> ... </h1>
<p> ... </p>
```

I have been trying to match it using the following pattern (with ignore-case and single-line options):

```
<([\w_]+?)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>
```

But all I get is only the first `<html>...</html>` since it nests the entire string.

How do I go about it?

Comment: See [*RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Use an HTML parser, like HtmlAgilityPack to easily parse HTML in .NET.

Comment: In the above link, and also in HtmlAgilityPack, how do I know/ignore tags that don't have an explicit closing tag. e.g. I don't want `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the result.

Comment: @PradeepKumar Try something with HtmlAgilityPack  and then ask where you get stuck.

Comment: Obligatory link: [You can't parse (X)HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: These are some fixed text files that won't change. I know I can use html DOM like loading in a webbrowser or use HtmlAgilityPack etc. And there are a lot of ways doing a loop etc. But my question was specific to regex whether such type of nesting/recursion is possible via RegEx. I'm trying to learn balancing groups in regex.